# INDEX and Match multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, vlookup, textjoin

I am trying to return the points rank value when both B2 on Player lookup and C2 on Player Lookup match the DvP dataset which i highlighted in the sheet.

So for example: For Lebron James I'd like to return the value from cell N89 based upon the previously mentioned cells (C2 and B2)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-NCFTXPCypCSm6EBaFqDG5Bsib1hwb29ck2Yiaq7EA/edit#gid=1377910615

Formula I tried `=INDEX(DvP!L4:T,MATCH(C2,DvP!M4:M,0),MATCH(B2,DvP!L4:L,0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(TRIM(B2&C2), {TRIM(DvP!L:L&DvP!M:M), DvP!N:N}, 2, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its giving me an "Did not find value 'SFLakers' in VLOOKUP evaluation." error

Comment: @TooTallDerr that is reasonable as because there is no `Lakers` in `DvP!M:M` range. if you want the result you wish for then `C2` needs to read `LAL` or `Lakers` would need to be located in `DvP!M89`